# Working with monad transformer RWST in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am using the monad transformer RWST in a Haskell project. Below is my source code:

```
type HSL a = RWST HBConfig [HBLog] a IO a       

runScript :: (HLanguage a, BuilderHSL a) 
          => HBConfig
          -> HSL a
          -> String
runScript hbConf srcHSL =  
    unsafePerformIO $ do
        (_, s, log) <- runRWST srcHSL hbConf initHLang
        return $ buildHSL hbConf s
```

I implemented the function `HSL HLangJS -> HLangJS` as shown below:

```
ujs :: HSL HLangJS -> HLangJS
ujs srcHSL =  
    unsafePerformIO $ do
        (a, s, log) <- runRWST srcHSL defaultHBConfig HLangJS
        return a
```

Everything is working. BUT!!! I'm sure this is not the best solution!
The config and logs must be requested from transformer as shown in this code:

```
ujs :: HSL a -> a
ujs rws = 
    unsafePerformIO $ liftIO $ do 
        c <- ask
        s <- get
        (a, _, _) <- runRWST rws c s
        return a
```

But this code is not working! How can I implement this?

Comment: In the last `ujs` you are trying to run an RWST action without supplying it with a "configuration" and an initial state.  You are trying to do `ask` and `get` - which means you are producing an RWST block - but then to *run* an RWST block in the same action.

Comment: Don't use `unsafePerformIO`. It's unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think your `HSL` type may be more better. `HSL` is monad but you've restricted it. The state type and monad "value" type may be different. Any time, you can restrict them.

```
type HSL l a = RWST HBConfig [HBLog] l IO a
```

or better:

```
type HSL l = RWST HBConfig [HBLog] l IO
```

Secondly, your `HSL` monad can have transformation `HSL l a -> l` only with defaults values for config and initial state. If you want hide this parameters, you should think about where you can get them? For example, you can get it from IO:

```
ujs :: HSL l a -> IO l
ujs act = do
    config <- ...
    initState <- ...
    fst <$> execRWST act config initState
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is the main problem for me: where can I get config and state? There was a couple of ideas. Work continues.

Comment: Why don't you want add them explicitly?

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I implemented the function  `ujs :: HSL HLangJS HLangJS -> HBConfig -> HLangJS -> HLangJS`. I reviewed the application architecture. Now the configuration and status passed to the function.